# I get a ruby interpreter error when I try to run tests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was writing tests for the invitations features and I get the following error. The error is really big so I will include the note at the end of the error. I get this error when I run the command `bundle exec rake test`.

```
7f394fb08000-7f394fb1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fb1a000-7f394fb3d000 r-xp 00000000 00:128 34                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f394fbdc000-7f394fbff000 r--s 00000000 00:128 2805                      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
7f394fbff000-7f394fd00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fd00000-7f394fd26000 r--p 00000000 00:128 132                       /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
7f394fd26000-7f394fd2b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fd2e000-7f394fd2f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fd2f000-7f394fd30000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fd30000-7f394fd33000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:3392]
7f394fd33000-7f394fd3a000 r--s 00000000 00:128 120                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f394fd3a000-7f394fd3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f394fd3c000-7f394fd3d000 r--p 00022000 00:128 34                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f394fd3d000-7f394fd3e000 rw-p 00023000 00:128 34                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f394fd3e000-7f394fd3f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe56bd9000-7ffe573d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe573d8000-7ffe573da000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe573da000-7ffe573dc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

I am also including the invitation_mailer_test that I was running.

```
require 'test_helper'

class InvitationMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "invitation_email" do
    scoreboard = scoreboards(:scoreboard_a)
    mail = InvitationMailer.send_invitation(scoreboard, email)
    assert_equal "Invitation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@scorecliq.com"], mail.from
    assert_match CGI::escape(email),    mail.body.encoded
  end


end
```

I have gotten this error once when I tried to run another tests. I am sure this is not a test error, its for something completely different. Has anybody every ran into such an error. Any suggestions on how to fix the error would be great.

Comment: Usually this error suggests a problem with your environment.  What happens when you run "bundle install", or  "brew doctor"?

Comment: @ruby_newbie, the bundle install command runs fine. I am not sure what brew doctor is. I don't want to run the command unless i know what it actually does.

Comment: Are you using homebrew?

Comment: Getting a hard crash on Ruby means you might want to rebuild or reinstall your Ruby. That's almost never the fault of your code.